# Can I get location information from Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a dashboard. This dashboard gets some informations from another websites that I developed. I want to view the locations of people visiting the websites I have developed in my dashboard project. Does Google Analytics share location informations with an API?

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Geo Network** dimensions:

```
Continent ga:continent
Sub Continent ga:subContinent
Country ga:country
Region ga:region
Metro ga:metro
City ga:city
Latitude ga:latitude
Longitude ga:longitude
Network Domain ga:networkDomain
Service Provider ga:networkLocation
City ID ga:cityId
Continent ID ga:continentId
Country ISO Code ga:countryIsoCode
Metro Id ga:metroId
Region ID ga:regionId
Region ISO Code ga:regionIsoCode
Sub Continent Code ga:subContinentCode
```

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/